# Supervisor exit status 255 not expected

Tags: supervisord

My working are failing with a spawn error:

```
2018-02-08 13:05:38,704 INFO exited: example-worker_00 (exit status 255; not expected)
2018-02-08 13:05:39,706 INFO gave up: example-worker_00 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

This is supervisor version 3.2.0 (latest available with apt-get) on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is my worker conf:

```
[program:example-worker] /etc/supervisor/conf.d/example-worker.conf
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/example.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=100 --daemon --queue=example-queue --timeout=290
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=2
user=forge
numprocs=2
logfile_maxbytes=10240
logfile_backups=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/example.com/storage/logs/workers/example-worker.log
```

I tried adding `startretries=2` because of the `too many start retries too quickly` part of the error as others have suggested, but that did not help.

Is there something wrong with my config? From what I can tell, this one looks the same as the workers that are starting successfully.

Comment: Your program fails to start entirely. Check your paths are correct.

Comment: That was the problem! The ones that were starting successfully had an extra part to the directory path.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error. I noticed that there was a directory error. Re-check the directory (***/app***) where command should be executed.

```
# Queue Worker
[program:queue-worker]
command=/usr/local/bin/php /app/artisan queue:work --tries=3
directory=/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
user=www
stderr_logfile=/app/storage/logs/supervisor.err.log
stdout_logfile=/app/storage/logs/supervisor.out.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found the user in my conf has not permission to write the log.

```
[root@ecs-gz-sdk01 logs]# php /data/www/demo/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3
[2019-11-19 15:39:25] Processed: App\Jobs\DoSth
[root@ecs-gz-sdk01 logs]# su www
[www@ecs-gz-sdk01 logs]$ php /data/www/demo/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3
[www@ecs-gz-sdk01 logs]$
```